# How to improve the VOICE of a Villain.

Tags: voice

My villain's voice is not convincing in my Action Movie. How I can improve his voice? 
Wich filters I can apply? 
I do not want to dub him.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you articulate what's wrong with the villain's voice as it stands? Knowing specific information about the problem may help us suggest a more appropriate solution.

Comment: It's tough to tell whether you mean human villain or monster as well.

Comment: If you upload a short sample of him, I can try to process it and give some in-detail advice. peace

Answer (score 6):

"...voice is not convincing..."

I believe you answered your own question.  It's a performance issue, so the only true way to fix it is to start with a convincing voice performance first.  The performance is key.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.  No matter what you do, if the source doesn't work look at fixing the source.

Answer (score 3):

- Lower or change formants with melodyne
- Pitch shift automation
- Extreme noisy Vocoder
- Load into a granulator and automate the parameters phrase by phrase so that the voice dissolves into granular bits at the end of a phrase or at some consonants.
- Unnatural Reverb. Hall reverb in small rooms, small reverb in big hall scenes.
- Layer that original with a distorted, pitch shifted version.
- get a very noisy vocoder layer and automate it in and out
- automate distortion effects to some consonants like shh tss css ect.
- use revered reverb to suck into some of his words.
- use a vocoder with pitch tracking and a very rich harmonic carrier. then use a wow/talk filter and automate the vocals according to the spoken vocals. then make this layer very deep.
- record some whispering, load it with reverb and automate volume, filter and pan on this to give some spooky vibe.
- Pitch shift the sound down, then pitch up the formants (autoamte if possible)
- use speakerphone or convolution reverb or re recording to emulate masks.
- use texture layers to fatten up the frequenzys. for exampel break glass or record some water flowing. then use a granualtor and pitch shift it down until lyou hear the little grains. automate the parameters to pronounce the phrase.
- record yourself saying the phrases and heavy process this layer.

if you cant mike it, you can mouth it

hope this list gives you some inspiration, peace

Answer (score 0):

A villian's voice needs to be menacing. I think in most cases it should be equalized to have a deeper tonality. Although if the character is more mysterious you would want to focus on making it sound airy and quiet. Can you describe the character a bit?

-Krux

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if it was a Male or Female or other - but maybe EQ to bring out some growl or shrill.   Maybe slight distortion.  Maybe another sound happening that ups the evil.  Maybe cut in a better take if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Avox Throat

Good to pitch and manipulate villians/monsters